# Set the last width of an item to full width using SpannedGridLayoutManager in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

So I am trying to make a gallery-like Instagram discover, using `SpannedGridLayoutManager`, and here is the layout manager for my `RecyclerView`.

```
SpannedGridLayoutManager manager = new SpannedGridLayoutManager(
        new SpannedGridLayoutManager.GridSpanLookup() {
            @Override
            public SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position) {
                // Conditions for 2x2 items
                if (position % 12 == 0 || position % 12 == 7) {
                    return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);
                } else {
                    return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
                }
            }

        },
        3, // number of columns
        1f // how big is default item
);
```

What I want to achieve is that if the last row contains only 1 or 2 items, I need the items to take the full width, without leaving a gap.

Hope you'll answer.